# Why is HAL_GetTick not protected by a CRITICAL SECTION?

Tags: arduino, stm32, interrupts

I'm trying to better understand atomicity in embedded systems.
While researching the topic, I encountered this problem:

In the STM32 HAL, the system tick is provided by `stm32XXXX_hal.c`.

```
// This is a simplification of the code found in stm32XXXX_hal.c
volatile uint32_t uwTick;

__weak void HAL_IncTick(void) //< called by the SysTick_Handler ISR
{
  uwTick += 1;
}

__weak uint32_t HAL_GetTick(void)
{
  return uwTick;
}
```

I don't understand why the `HAL_GetTick` function has no CRITICAL_SECTION to guarantee atomicity. Surely, it's possible for the systick ISR to be triggered in the middle of `HAL_GetTick`.

For reference, here's what the Arduino equivalent (`millis()`) is doing.

```
// wiring.c
unsigned long millis()
{
        unsigned long m;
        uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;
 
        // disable interrupts while we read timer0_millis or we might get an
        // inconsistent value (e.g. in the middle of a write to timer0_millis)
        cli();
        m = timer0_millis;
        SREG = oldSREG;
 
        return m;
}
```

What am I missing?

---

EDIT:
By CRITICAL_SECTION, I mean sections of code where ISR are disabled.

Comment: I think you should first explain what is this CRITICAL_SECTION you speak of. Is it a macro or function, is it just for disabling interrupts in hardware or some RTOS function to prevent task switching? Also which STM32, because implementation will likely be different on a single core and multi core STM32 MCUs. It still does not change the answer though, on this 32-bit micro the native atomic data type is a 32-bit variable and on a 8-bit micro a 32-bit variable can not be atomic.

Comment: @Justme You're right. What I mean by critical sections is disabling the ISR. I used this therm because its the macro name in a few OpenSource RTOS.

Comment: Incrementing a uint32_t is fundamentally atomic on (probably) all ARM 32 bit and better machines. You will either get N or N+1. There was an interesting problem here where someone was calling HAL_GetTick() from an ISR and it was never updating  because it was pre-empted by the ISR.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the STM32, read and writes of 32 bit values are inherently atomic as it is a 32 bit cpu. In contrast, the average Arduino uses an AVR cpu which is 8bit. To read/write a 32 bit value requires 4 reads or writes. Without protection an interrupt could occur during these operations. Thus protection is required.

Further info: i don’t think there is anything explicit in the ST docs about atomicity. Since the ST Arm cpu can read/write 32 bit values in one instruction that implies the operation is atomic. In the systick isr, the increment is not atomic as a read/modify/write operation is done - this will most likely be 3 instructions. Assuming there is no isr with a higher priority than systick that modifies this variable, then we’re ok. If your application code was to do this, then you would need to protect that operation. Since you should only read the value, then an interrupt cannot affect the read operation. If the value was 64 bits and requiring two reads, then protection would be required.

On Arm Cortex M3 and up there is a mechanism to raise the system priority to mask interrupt sources below that priority rather than disable/enable interrupts. This would be the preferred method.

Once you get cache, dma, multicore or out of order execution, then you need to think more carefully about atomicity. The Arm has instructions like ‘DMB’ to create a memory barrier to ensure the hardware behaves how we want in certain circumstances.

Comment: In his CppCon 2017 talk, Fedor Pikus says that we can't assume any operation is atomic. Is he saying this because of memory hierarchy?  Basically: because my STM32 does not have any cache layers, I can assume `return uwTick` will be atomic?

Comment: @gberth Well, that's a CppCon talk, not a STM32con talk. C++ doesn't say that operations are atomic. Some processors make them atomic anyway. But you have to understand your processor and compiler well, before you can rely on this.

Comment: @gberth by the way, notice that single-core processors are a lot more predictable (when it comes to multithreading and interrupts), because the core will always do an instruction before it does the next one, and it always sees its own cache. If you have two cores then you can have different instructions running at the same time, plus cache coherency and stuff like that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @user253751. I agree with you, understanding the CPU is critical. Are the C11 atomics used at all in embedded? Or do people only rely on disabling ISR to create critical sections?

Comment: @gberth You can use them if you want but I'm not sure they are very useful on single-processor systems where you know the CPU type. You might want to use them, if you want the same code to compile on the embedded system and also on your PC. And you might have a multi-core embedded system, in which case they're indispensible of course.

Comment: @gberth if the compiler knows that normal variables are already atomic, then using atomic variables shouldn't cost anything, because the compiler should just treat them as normal variables.

Comment: @Kartman I didn't find anything about the atomicity of operations in the reference manual. Where could I find this information for myself? Thanks again for your answer!

Comment: @gberth Assuming this is an ARM processor, you would look in the ARM ARM (which documents the ARM ISA specifications) entry for your specific ARM revision.

Comment: @gberth in STM32, one always can find a memory area which ensures atomicity (for example, DTCM or other internal SRAM) and place the uwTick there. There may be other, problematic, memory regions that do not ensure atomicity though I struggle to name them - just do not put uwTick there.

Comment: `uwTick` is defined at the top of `stm32g4xx_hal.c` so it's in the .data section. What you're saying is that it would be possible for a variable on, let's say, the stack to be non-atomic?

Comment: If stack operations were non-atomic, think of the problems you would have! You may run into problems with dma to the same area of memory as your stack or variables as the dma accesses memory directly whereas the cpu (assuming one that has caching) goes via the cache. Certain sdram controllers can do out of order writes that can cause bizarre problems in very specific circumstances. For the most part you should be safe with the ‘usual’ memory in your micro.